# Send string from client to server via socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets

I want to send a string from a client to a server via socket. I tried doing this three ways (write, puts and print)

```
hostname = 'localhost'
port = 3000
s = TCPSocket.new(hostname, port)

s.write("hello")
s.puts("hello")
s.print("hello")

s.close
```

but it gives me an error (the error does not appear on the browser but on the terminal):
`ERROR bad Request-Line 'hello'`.

Is it possible to send strings from the client to the server or is it only from server to client?

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.1

Comment: Do you have a tcp server application listening on port 3000 on the same machine? Otherwise, you won't be able to establish a tcp connection via handshake to send message.

Comment: @CodePainters said what I forgot:I want to talk to WEBrick, and yes, is in port 3000. We finally did it in another way, but thank you anyway

Comment: If CodePainters answer helped you @itziki , you should upvote / accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the server doesn't like your `Hello` line. You mention Ruby and Rails, I guess you want to talk to `WEBrick` HTTP server - why don't you speak HTTP then?

If you want to implement HTTP client, take a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm

Under `A Tiny Web Browser` section you'll find a working HTTP client using `TCPSocket`, as well as [Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) example.

If HTTP is what you need, `Net::HTTP` is the way to go, implementing HTTP sounds like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, you saved my monthly salary.